# Error in reading a csv file from aws glue catalog table , data also contain coma

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-glue-spark

I have s3 file in csv format , which is reading through aws glue job using aws glue catalog . There is  3 fields in s3 file. as follows

```
ID,NAME,COMMENT
1,"XYZ","COMMENT1,COMMENT2"
2,"abc","COMMENT3"
3,"mno","COMMENT4"
```

The issue is while reading with csv as "," as delimiter , the third column is not parsed properly as data also have comma.

Comment: Is the table already wrong when querying it with Athena?

Comment: Table is good. It is receiving data from multiple source for which files having same structure . I would like to know how can I read a field in quotes